# Documentation for uinput

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying very hard to find the documentation for the `uinput` but the only thing I have found was the `linux/uinput.h`. I have also found some tutorials on the internet but no documentation at all!

For example I would like to know what `UI_SET_MSCBIT` does but I can't find anything about it.

How does people know how to use `uinput`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it takes some investigation effort for such subtle things. From
`drivers/input/misc/uinput.c` and `include/uapi/linux/uinput.h` files you can see bits for `UI_SET_*` definitions, like this:

- `MSC`
- `REL`
- `LED`

etc.

Run next command in kernel sources directory:

```sh
$ git grep --all-match -e 'MSC' -e 'REL' -e 'LED' -- Documentation/*
```

or use regular `grep`, if your kernel doesn't have `.git` directory:

```sh
$ grep -rl MSC Documentation/* | xargs grep -l REL | xargs grep -l LED
```

You'll get this file: [Documentation/input/event-codes.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt), from which you can see:

> `EV_MSC`: Used to describe miscellaneous input data that do not fit into other types.
>
> `EV_MSC` events are used for input and output events that do not fall under other categories.
>
> A few `EV_MSC` codes have special meaning:
>
> - `MSC_TIMESTAMP`: Used to report the number of microseconds since the last reset. This event should be coded as an `uint32` value, which is allowed to wrap around with no special consequence. It is assumed that the time difference between two consecutive events is reliable on a reasonable time scale (hours).  A reset to zero can happen, in which case the time since the last event is unknown.  If the device does not provide this information, the driver must not provide it to user space.

I'm afraid this is the best you can find out there for `UI_SET_MSCBIT` out there.